# Fortify .NET Translate command

Tags: .net, fortify

Is there a generic command that can be used to find all necessary files for Fortify translation using SCA and translating a .NET project on the command line?

If I am translating other peoples projects, can I use,

`sourceanalyzer -b "Build ID" devenv BuildID.sln /Rebuild Debug`

with the latest Visual Studio installed and expect it to translate all projects correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as the project you want to translate will compile on that computer.

If you do run into problems it normally has something to do with the target project on that machine with that version of Visual Studio.

A simple check is to run `devenv BuildID.sln` from the command line.  You want Visual Studio to open and have no dialog boxes popuping up (source control is a common one I see).  Once it can be openned without any dialog popups, next make sure a rebuild or clean/build will successfully happen.

**Update based on comment:**

For a generic scan against an already compiled code you can:

```
sourceanalyzer -b mybuild -vsversion 14.0 -libdirs **/* **/*
```

You can run this from the base file for the project.

- `-libdirs **/*` should specify where System and Third Party .dlls are. (Fortify will automatically check the standard locations for Microsoft's System's dlls.
- The second **/* should be the programs source code and dlls/pdb files.

Running it with the correct version of vsversion (needs to be on the machine) Fortify should be able to find the ildasm.exe, but if it cannot find it add the following option to the command pointing to the ildasm.exe

```
-Dcom.fortify.sca.IldasmPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a another generic command which I can use with a project which has already been built in debug mode?

Comment: Can I use something like this, `**/**/*.dll`, or this, `**/*.dll`, for finding all .dll files?

Comment: `**/*.dll` will look for all dlls in the current and sub-directories.

Comment: Would the paths you have specified in your answer recursively search for all necessary files or would I need to specify the files for each individual project I translate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OS pipe command with Fortify Translation command,it will print  all translated dll in a text file i.e.

Fortify Translation command >> directory_path

But still you have to use the translation command using sourceanalyzer.exe

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited my question as it was a little unclear.